# Trouble with curl and rest

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, rest, curl

I'm having a problem using curl to pull a specific task from sharepoint 2010 enterpise.

We use a very complicated extendscript to process images into archive locations and create web images.

We have these tasks we call photo orders.  Its a task started in sharepoint, its given a tracking number (which does not match its sharepoint ID).
When an employee completes these photo orders, (or any image) its sent to this extendscript.

The extendscript runs on Mac OS X, when the photo order comes in, I want the script to set the 
photo order task to complete.  Here is where the problem is.  When i try to curl just the specific task:

```
curl --ntlm --user user:pass http://<sharepoint>/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/PhotoRequests?$filter=TrackingNo eq '21186_QC_I'
```

I get the entire list of all tasks in this location, and curl comes back saying:

> Can not resolve eq and can not resolve 21186_QC_I

I've tried encapsulating the url in quotes, I've added `+` in spaces, I've even added `%20` for space, and `%27` for the `'`s.

I can not manage to find something that works.  I'm hoping someone else has had experience with rest and curl together for this.